# NFL teams beating the same team 3 times in a season

Tags: american-football, trivia, nfl

As of the end of week 15 of 2016 season, the Dallas Cowboys and the New York Giants have a chance of facing off in the playoffs. The Giants have dealt the Cowboys their only 2 losses of the season so far.
Teams that are in the same division play each other 2 times during the regular season. So to beat a team 3 times, they must also meet in the playoffs. I'm wondering how many times has a team beaten a division rival 3 times in the same season in the NFL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They always say that it is hard to beat the same team three times in one season.  However, it happens periodically.  Since 1950, it has happened 17 times:

- [2009 Dallas Cowboys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Dallas_Cowboys_season) over Philadelphia Eagles
- [2008 Pittsburgh Steelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Pittsburgh_Steelers_season) over Baltimore Ravens
- [2004 St. Louis Rams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_St._Louis_Rams_season) over Seattle Seahawks
- [2002 Pittsburgh Steelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_Pittsburgh_Steelers_season) over Cleveland Browns
- [2000 New York Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_New_York_Giants_season) over Philadelphia Eagles
- [1999 Tennessee Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_Tennessee_Titans_season) over Jacksonville Jaguars
- [1997 Green Bay Packers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1997_Green_Bay_Packers_season) over Tampa Bay Buccaneers
- [1997 New England Patriots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1997_New_England_Patriots_season) over Miami Dolphins
- [1994 Pittsburgh Steelers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994_Pittsburgh_Steelers_season) over Cleveland Browns
- [1993 Los Angeles Raiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1993_Los_Angeles_Raiders_season) over Denver Broncos
- [1991 Kansas City Chiefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991_Kansas_City_Chiefs_season) over Los Angeles Raiders
- [1986 New York Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1986_New_York_Giants_season) over Washington Redskins
- [1982 Miami Dolphins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1982_Miami_Dolphins_season) over New York Jets (in a shortened season)
- [1965 Green Bay Packers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1965_Green_Bay_Packers_season) over Baltimore Colts
- [1964 Buffalo Bills](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1964_Buffalo_Bills_season) over San Diego Chargers
- [1958 New York Giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_New_York_Giants_season) over Cleveland Browns
- [1952 Detroit Lions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1952_Detroit_Lions_season) over Los Angeles Rams

Comment: Just for good measure, do you have a source?  Did you compile these yourself???  If so, from where?  That way it can be validated since it's a pretty complex list.  But good answer

Comment: @JeopardyTempest My source is each Wikipedia link; you can click on them and see the schedule for each team that year. I found a couple of partial lists online by Googling and filled them in with research from Wikipedia.

Comment: I'd like to know how hard it actually is.  It happened 17 times out of how many opportunities?  How many times has a team defeated another team twice and then met a third time in the playoffs?

Comment: Fun fact for the 1999 titans vs jaguars: The jaguars got beaten 3 times throughout the whole season. And all 3 were to the titans!

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to supplement [Ben Miller's answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/15218/3763) with some information on how difficult it actually is to defeat a team 3 times in one season. It is often said that it is very difficult for an NFL team to beat another team 3 times in one season, but it turns out that is not true.

According to an ESPN [article](https://www.espn.com/nfl/story/_/id/30698727/nfl-experts-debate-deshaun-watson-trade-fits-playoff-teams-upset-alert-steelers-future-bold-predictions), from 1970 through 2019, teams that swept an opponent during the regular season and then faced them again in the playoffs won the playoff game 67% of the time:

> I don't buy the old adage that "it's tough to beat a team three times," because since 1970 teams that beat a team twice in the regular season and saw them again in the playoffs are 14-7 in the rematch.